# Online XML Viewer

Tags: xml, view

I have a webserver with XML files on it. I want to find an online application that I can put on that server that will give Users access to view the raw XML files without being able to edit them.
Does anybody have any ideas?
This is a Windows server.

Comment: Have you tried this?https://devtoolsonline20190908040816.azurewebsites.net/DevTools/Prettify_XML

Answer (score 3):

If you link to them using a browser it will display them read-only and provide formatting.

Comment: Assuming the browser's MIME settings are configured to display XML files and not download them, that is.

Answer (score 1):

Free online XML Viewer/Formatter.
http://www.xmlviewer.org

Answer (score 1):

Try this one http://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer the best one I found online.

Follow this steps.

1. Open http://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer and Create Account
2. Input your XML and Save.
3. That will provide a link , which you can share to your client.

Answer (score 0):

A different view on XML is offered by https://www.luxonsoftware.com/xmlviewer as it is not based on the ubiquitous treeview. Instead this viewer dissects the data contained in de XML file into flat data tables, similar to the way an Excel file structures data into sheets with rows and columns. Once you are on the web page just point your browser to XML document you want to view and click on the button (there's only one button). The resulting HTML can be shared with third parties.